# can't use favicon and style sheet at the same time, they break eachother

Tags: html, favicon

here is my problem: 

I have these 2  tags in my header but they are fighting each other. If I put the rel tag for the shortcut icon below the rel tag for the style sheet (because it is parsed after) my stylesheet breaks and does not display but the icon is there. If I leave it as is the icon does not display. I am obviously doing something wrong but I can't figure it out. Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="tophat2.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css""/>

Comment: You should include the relevant code in the question, not an incomplete code in the question. You should check your code with http://validator.w3.org. The short snippet has a syntax error, an extra quotation mark. The odds are that your real code has just some trivial syntax error that can easily be fixed by using a validator.

Comment: This is also a duplicate of the poster’s own http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193307/stylesheet-link-rel-and-shortcut-icon-link-rel-override-each-other-so-i-cannot-u

Answer (score 1):

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="tophat2.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="shortcut icon" href="tophat2.jpg"/>
```

Remove the `rel="shortcut icon"` and the `href="tophat2.jpg"` in the second tag and close the first one.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="tophat2.ico"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
```

Comment: I tried combining the 2 tags but that didn't work either<link rel="shortcut icon" href="tophat2.ico"> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/> combine to <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" rel="shortcut icon" href="tophat.ico"/> all as one tag but that didn't work

Comment: The first `link` tag isn't closed.

Comment: ok I have <link rel="shortcut icon" href="tophat2.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/> like this one after another and it still doesn't work.

Comment: my bad, closed the first tag, still not working though<link rel="shortcut icon" href="tophat2.ico"/> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/> with all typos fixed I retried and got the same results. If I switch the order of the tags one breaks the other but they each work individually. The typos were from copy and paste after a lot of experiments.

Answer (score 0):

Try to delete this line:

And upload your favicon to the web server root and rename it to favicon.ico

Comment: my bad, closed the first tag, still not working though<link rel="shortcut icon" href="tophat2.ico"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>

Comment: sorry, try to delete <link rel="shortcut icon" href="tophat2.ico"> and then upload your favicon to the web server root and rename it to favicon.ico

Comment: if i delete the short cut icon tag then I won't have any icon. my problem isn't that the icon won't show up, because it does, but when it does it is parsed after the stylesheet rel tag and breaks my stylesheet for some reason. Does everyone use 2 link rel tags at once to do this?