# stylesheet link rel and shortcut icon link rel override each other so I cannot use my stylesheet and icon at the same time

Tags: html, icons, stylesheet

Here is my problem, I have 2 link rel tags in my html index header. One tag is for my stylesheet the other is a shortcut icon link rel to use a icon in my browser tab (fyi using FF19).

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="tophat2.ico"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>
```

Each rel link works fine on its own. when I have them one after another though the one on the bottom (being parsed second) is the only one that is displayed however. They appear to be overriding eachother so I conclude I cannot have both a icon shortcut and a stylesheet each as a separate rel link but that is the only method I can find via Google so I am stuck.

Comment: <link rel="shortcut icon" href="tophat2.ico"/> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"/>   (in this order the style sheet is working but not the icon)

Comment: You can use code blocks to post html. I added them for you. Click edit on your question to see how.

Comment: And if you switch them?

Comment: If I switch them around then the icon appears in my tab but the CSS no longer works. It is quite frustrating.

Comment: This is also a duplicate of the poster’s own http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15193029/cant-use-favicon-and-style-sheet-at-the-same-time-they-break-eachother and does not describe a reproducible problem.

Comment: I need your help.
Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/q/66546478/14467588.

Answer (score 0):

See http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/rel-shortcut-icon. It says:

> Most sites use the following HTML to specify a favicon:
>
> ```
> <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico">
> ```
>
> Looks okay, right? Guess what — it isn’t!
>
> Today, I learned that shortcut is not a valid link relation. Indeed,
>   it doesn’t show up in section 4.12.5 of the HTML5 specification on
>   ‘link types’. It is, in fact, proprietary to Internet Explorer.
>   Without IE, rel="icon" would suffice to specify a favicon.

Since you are using Firefox, that would explain why it isn't working. Try just this:

```
<link rel="icon" href="tophat2.ico"/>
```

But be aware that this may not work in IE 8 or below. Later on in that same post it says:

> If the shortcut value is omitted from the rel attribute, Internet
>   Explorer ignores the declaration entirely, searches for a file called
>   favicon.ico in the site root, and uses that instead. In fact, almost
>   every browser does that when there’s no link rel="icon" specified.
>   Using rel="icon shortcut" won’t work in IE either, since it doesn’t
>   treat the rel attribute as a space-separated list.
>
> Just make sure to always put the favicon in the root directory of your
>   site, and name it favicon.ico

Comment: Made the change and it works to display the icon but it still breaks my style sheet and my stylesheet being on the second line still breaks the icon rel link :(

Answer (score 0):

OK I FIXED IT!!! I have no idea why the **** this worked but it did. I copied my rel link=icon
tag and pasted it as a duplicate above the 2 waring rel links. The duplicate being parsed first appears broken which doesn't matter but now the 2 below work so I have a working stylesheet and icon. Thanks for trying to help everybody. This one shall probably remain a mystery.